# JSON.parse returns junk in Node.JS

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

I do an HTTP GET request to get a json string. I get back someting like `{"a":2,"b":3,"c":3}` . I know this because I can run console.log on it, and get my nice JSON string. However, when I try to parse it with JSON.parse I get something like `{0:123,1:63,...}`. Basically, it shows the ascii values of my string rather than parsing the JSON object. Why is this happening?

Comment: Does this also happen if you simply execute `JSON.parse('{"a":1}')` from the command line?

Answer (score 0):

Code:

```
var jsonString = '{"a":2,"b":3,"c":3}';
var object = JSON.parse(jsonString);

console.log(object);
console.log(object.a);
console.log(object['b']);
```

Output:

```
{ a: 2, b: 3, c: 3 }
2
3
```

A more specific example of your problem would be helpful, as something else is obviously going on.